# Text Layouts and customization and difference web part zones

Tags: column

I know what is different between "Page Layouts" and "Text Layouts". 
But what about web part zones? How web part zones fit in this picture?
Is web part zone just one small part inside Text Layout, which have one webpart or?

Also, how I can customize "Text Layouts", is it even possible?
Example, if I want choose "Two columns with header and footer" and I want remove top column or change it size. Is it possbile and how? I use SharePoint Foundation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpart zones are nothing but asp.net tags that finally renders as a block level element like table or div in the html output.

They act as logical containers for different functional outputs in a web page. In sharepoint they are declared with in a page layout.

**Master Page** is what gives the basic structure to the page like header,footer and content area.

**Page Layout** gives structure to the content area like one column,two columns,three columns ,etc.

**Web Part Zone** resides with in these columns as container for webparts.

**Text Layout** is similar to page layout except for the fact that it is not available when the page is a publishing page.

You can open a wiki page in SharePoint designer and modify the text layouts.

Comment: Can I add "text layouts" using Visual Studio? Example, if I create site and I want it to use default different "text layout".